# Prime number program for java

Tags: java, numbers, primes

I'm new to programming and need help on a java program. I want my program to return all the prime numbers between 1 and 10.

```
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        int factors = 0;
        int j=1;

        while(j<=i){
            if(i % j == 0){
                factors++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(factors==2){
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
```

Instead of receiving 2,3,5 and 7 I receive 3,4,6,and 8

Comment: there are enough examples of such programs on the internet please make the effort to look for them

Comment: The OP is trying to find the error in his own program. An example of a different program won't be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just print i instead of j

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
    int factors = 0;
    int j=1;

    while(j<=i){
        if(i % j == 0){
            factors++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(factors==2){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You print `j` instead of `i`, change your `println()` line to:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Your results are 'one too large' as `j = i + 1` after the `while`-loop.